# Speech recognition with punctuation

Tags: ios, swift3, speech-recognition

After doing some tests on the speech framework, I've realized that there was no punctuation in the result. Is there a way to trigger it? I've seen that Siri does recognize punctuation so I think it should be doable.

Comment: Say: "Hello comma world exclamation mark"

Comment: yeah this works, but I meant a natural understanding of punctuation ...

Comment: No such thing is built in.

Comment: siri makes the difference between "those are blue" and "those are blue ?" So i hoped I was missing a parameter somewhere, anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: I have never seen Siri insert punctuation automatically. I Have to say: "How do you do question mark My name is Duncan comma and I am very pleased to meet you period" in order to get it to insert punctuation.

Comment: You guys are right, I have tested it in various languages, and there is no puctuation. This makes sense since it s a very tricky game to assess pucntuation, especially in complex languages like latin ones where a question cannot be triggered through a sentence construction scheme, it has to do with the way we percieve phonetic intention ... if this makes sense. Anyway thanks for all of you for taking time to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually punctuation is assigned as a separate post-processing step.

For English you can use [Punctuator](https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2), for other languages you have to build models for post-processing, it would be a bit more complicated.