# Splitting german chunk of text into sentences by using Xamarin / Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: c#, nlp, speech-recognition, speech, google-cloud-speech

I'm using the Google Cloud Speech API in a Xamarin.Forms Application. Unfortunatlely, the API just returns spoken language in a chunk of text without punctuation, question marks and so on. I know that can be done by using the Google Cloud Natural Language API, but it doesn't exist for the german language yet. I also looked after the Stanford NLP but I couldn't find out how to split the text into sentences.

For example, i wanna turn

"Die Sonne scheint die Katze ist weiss" (The sun is shining the cat is white)

into

"Die Sonne scheint. Die Katze ist weiss." (The sun is shining. The cat is white.)

Comment: Might have better luck with Microsoft's [Linguistic Analysis API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/linguistic-analysis-api).

Comment: The problem is even visible with your own example: How do you know that the sentence isn't split by a comma? It actually would have been more intuitive for me.

Comment: @MetaColon Well, that would be a run-on sentence. This is a comma splice: two independent clauses separated by a comma.

Comment: @Romoku I had a look at that one but it simply doenst seem to do what I need if i try it in the online demo..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech recognition with punctuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728618/speech-recognition-with-punctuation)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev unfortunately there isn't a good answer yet in your given thread.. i would like to ask if there are already some solutions working with the german language.